# Why can't I connect with other devices using google's play games multiplayer service?

Tags: google-play-games

I have several games to play with my friends and they have this multiplayer feature that can connect to other devices by using the Google Play Games.

But why can't I really use this? It stays on loading forever.. Did I do something wrong? I've searched around and they said that feature only works for the exact same 'play games' version. Well, for some devices they have this app built in on their devices so sometimes the version is a bit different (x.x.1234 and x.x.1233).

Knowing that, I figured out I might try to download the apks for the exact versions to match with one another, and surprisingly it works.

But after a few days it doesn't work back again! Tried reinstalling the apks manually like I did before, but no luck this time.

What is actually wrong here?